# How to define a common mutex between two classes in C++

Tags: multithreading, class, global-variables, mutex, public

I know how to define a mutex as a private variable in a class and then use it in the member functions of that class. But, now I want to define a mutex which can be used in two classes. I mean, I have two classes (class A and class B) and I want to define a mutex which is followed and used in member functions of both class A and class B. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's trivial if you don't mind making the mutex a public variable. If you want to keep it private, then how about declaring a wrapper class that contains a `private` mutex, and methods that lock the mutex and then operate on instances of each of the two classes at the same time?

Comment: If I define the mutex as public in one class the how can I use it in the other class? Can I pass it? @SolomonSlow

Comment: Locking a mutex doesn't have any effect on any other variable in a program. The only thing it prevents is, it prevents other threads from locking the same mutex at the same time. If you don't want threads to interfere with each other, then it's up to you to ensure that the threads will never access the shared variables except when the mutex is locked.